# Height issue appear while i make ul list similar visual like table

Tags: html, css

I have set of ul list. Those lists appears like 2 column table which i needed. I have made it. But issue occurring when any list content increased. Issue is equal height not applied. So it gets broken table look.

Here my  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uft7uv3/2/) and below is the snippet

```css
    ul.filter_list {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      border: 1px #000 solid;
    }
    li.filter_cell {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      padding: 4px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-top: 1px #000 solid;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    ul.filter_list li:nth-child(odd) {
      border-right: 1px #000 solid;
    }
    .filtertab_title {
      font-family: 'open_sansbold';
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      margin-left: 16px
    }
    .filtertab_value {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 16px
    }
```

```html
<ul class="filter_list">
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">PMT Base Name</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">Category</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">Pattern Category Name and documentation information for lorem text goes here dummy text</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">GMT Base Name</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">Measurement</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">Base Name</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why can't you use tables instead of `li` ?

Comment: Good Question Sooraj. Thing is i need them to convert into ng-repeat (angularjs). So i opted to go with li.

Comment: Kumar You can use ng-repeat for tables rows also. Please check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/

Comment: Yes agreed. But I need two column table. Basically this table will be shown in popup form. That popup width allows 2 column for a row.

Comment: Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/soorajchn/h7rfyu7z/ - ?

Comment: yes but different datas in each cell like my fiddle url

Comment: That you can change using the scope variable.

Comment: its my fiddle. Pls have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/3uft7uv3/2/

Answer (score 0):

change the structure

```
<div class="filter_divst">
<div class="filter-row"> <!--add this element to create a row for 2 columns-->
    <div class="filter_cell">
      <div class="filtertab_title">PMT Base Name</div>
      <div class="filtertab_value">
        <select class="filtertab_select">
          <option>Any</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_cell">
      <div class="filtertab_title">Category</div>
      <div class="filtertab_value">
        <select class="filtertab_select">
          <option>Any</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="filter-row"> <!--add this element to create a row for 2 columns-->
    <div class="filter_cell">
      <div class="filtertab_title">Pattern Category Name and documentation information for lorem text goes here dummy text</div>
      <div class="filtertab_value">
        <select class="filtertab_select">
          <option>Any</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_cell">
      <div class="filtertab_title">GMT Base Name</div>
      <div class="filtertab_value">
        <select class="filtertab_select">
          <option>Any</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-row"> <!--add this element to create a row for 2 columns-->
    <div class="filter_cell">
      <div class="filtertab_title">Measurement</div>
      <div class="filtertab_value">
        <select class="filtertab_select">
          <option>Any</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="filter_cell">
    <div class="filtertab_title">Base Name</div>
    <div class="filtertab_value">
      <select class="filtertab_select">
        <option>Any</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



div.filter_list
{
    margin:0px; 
  padding:0px; 
  width:100%;
  border:1px #000 solid;/*add this */
}
.filter-row{ /*add this */
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-display:flex;
}
div.filter_cell
{
  width:50%; 
  padding:4px; 
  box-sizing:border-box;/*add this */
  border-collapse:collapse; 
  border-top:1px #000 solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-left: 1px #000 solid;
}
```